# Split user input integer and then perform mathematical operations on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a user to enter a 3 digit number and then split that number into three separate numbers so that I can divide the first number by the second number and add that result to the last number.

```
try:
   inp = int(input('Enter a 3 digit number: '))
    [int(i) for i in str(inp)]
    n1 = [0]
    n2 = [1]
    n3 = [2]
except ValueError:
    print('is not an integer')
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('cannot divide by zero')
div_num = n1 / n2
result = div_num + n3
    print(result)
```

I know I can't do the math on string characters, but how can I fix this?

Comment: `inp = [int(x) for x in input('Enter a 3 digit number: ')]` should do

Comment: can you edit to explain what your input is? like `456`, or `123` ? because some answers didn't get the input format you want.

Answer (score 1):

This code makes no sense:

```
[int(i) for i in str(inp)]
n1 = [0]
n2 = [1]
n3 = [2]
```

the first line does the job but discards the result. The next lines define lists containing 1 element, 0, 1, and 2...

If the input is guaranteed to be 3 characters long, you can use

```
n1,n2,n3 = map(int,input('Enter a 3 digit number: '))
```

`map` is unpacked into the 3 variables.

I would advise a control to avoid unpacking errors though:

```
s = input('Enter a 3 digit number: ')
if len(s) == 3:
   try:
      n1,n2,n3 = map(int,s)
      # continue the processing
   except ValueError:
      # catch wrong integer exception
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
>>>
>>> a, b, c = (int(str) for str in input('Enter a 3 digit number: ').split(' '))
Enter a 3 digit number: 20 4 15
>>>
>>> a / b + c
20.0
>>>
```